# OpenCV Cascade classifier - Can recognize some different objects?

Tags: opencv, cascade-classifier, viola-jones

my goal is detect different type of objects (green/red apples, coffee cup and a glass).
I tried to using a cascade classifier to detect a generic apple in the scene and works successfully.

There is some method to train my classifier to recognize the 4 objects with Cascade classifier? I need to know exactly WHICH object I detected and not only if there is a generic target-object in the scene.

Thanks to all

Comment: A classifier will make a yes/no decision, so if you have 3 different types of objects, you will need 3 different classifiers to tell them apart. For the case of red/green apple, you probably don't need separate cascades for that -- once you know there's an apple in given ROI, you can analyse the hue to tell them apart.

Comment: As I thought. Thank you very much